# Motivation of Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, topology

What is the historical motivation of continuous functions? Also, does anyone know who first isolated the idea?

Comment: [According](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) to Wikipedia (and I've read it elsewhere) topology goes back to the ideas of *geometria situs* (the geometry of place) and *analysis situs* (the picking apart of place) by Liebniz in the 17th C, unfortunately the article doesn't explain how.

Answer (score 5):

Isolation of the modern concept is [generally attributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#History) to Bolzano ([1817](https://books.google.com/books?id=uccGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA11&dq=Stetigkeit); [translation](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=572277)) and/or Cauchy ([1821](https://archive.org/stream/coursdanalysedel00cauc#page/34)), with some controversy on their independence: see Grattan-Guinness ([1970](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0198.00601)), Freudenthal ([1971](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.01010)). Kline ([1972](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=472307), [p. 950](https://archive.org/stream/MathematicalThoughtFromAncientToModernTimes#page/n968)) says Bolzano’s motivation was to rigorously prove the fundamental theorem of algebra, and on his way, the intermediate value theorem — stated in his memoir’s title.